# Remove a line from a file using a variable line number

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

This is probably a simple one to answer, but I'm stuck, so here goes.

```
sed '3d' filename    # (or something like that)
```

I'm having trouble trying to use a `$VARIABLE` instead of the number.

Anyone know how to get this to work, or any alternative options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you mean this:

```
bash$ VARIABLE=3
bash$ sed "${VARIABLE}d" filename
```

(I'm not sure if this is correct use of the `sed` command, I just know that's how you would use a variable next to a letter in bash syntax.)

Comment: Considering a range (`$ sed "1,100d" filename`), when you have, for example, to receive the higher limit through a variable, this must be done step-by-step: `export limit=100; export range="1,$limit"; sed "${range}d" filename`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ variable=3
$ awk -vvar="$variable" 'NR!=var' file
```

using the shell(bash)

```
variable=3
i=1
while read -r line
do
  [ "$i" -ne "$variable" ] && echo "$line"
  ((i++))
done <"file" > newfile
```

Comment: +1. alternate variable assignment for `awk` (POSIX IIRC): `awk 'NR!=var' vvar="$variable" file` :)

Comment: the only problem with that alternate syntax is that if `vvar` will not have a value inside BEGIN block.